# How to remove icon of uninstalled program previously installed via Wine

Tags: wine, gnome-shell, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I recently uninstalled MS Office 2010 on PlayOnLinux and then reinstalled it. However I found that the previous icon is still in the menu as it is shown here:

[image]

The same problem also happens with Powerpoint and excel. If I click the previous one, PlayOnLinux will tell me that this app is crashed, however I cound't find these apps inside the PlayOnLinux either.

Any idea?